# Can a Ubuntu computer work on a Windows network?

Tags: networking, windows, file-sharing

I have a desktop running Windows XP, and I am seriously considering switching to Linux/Ubuntu once support from MS ends in a few weeks.  However, I have other computers in my house, all running relatively more modern variants of Windows, and thus part of a Windows network.  Can a Ubuntu machine function as part of a Windows network?  I know that I *should* be able to connect to my router via wire/wireless (although I'm a bit concerned at the number of questions I see regarding various people's connectivity issues in Ubuntu)...I'm just wondering if I'll still be able to do folder/file shares, etc.  Also, if anyone has any suggestions regarding any potential pitfalls I could avoid, that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i've stuck my ubuntu laptop on my network at home, and also on client sites never had any bother connecting - also using proxies (some small tweaks needed there). BUT just in case, i installed VirtualBox with a small windows environment - just in case there were any functions i could only do in windows - and i have to say i've found nothing yet that Ubuntu cant handle!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install Samba on your Ubuntu machine](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-samba-in-ubuntu-for-file-sharing/).
I don't have a windows machine, but using samba I can share files with my Android device without a problem.